Не удается получить данные из MySQL для python3.4 приложение
Есть несколько таблиц из которых получаю значения с помощью шаблона запроса.
Код шаблона запроса:
curs.execute(
    'SELECT DATE_USER, ' + col_name + ' AS cname, ' + col_sum
    + ' AS csum FROM ' + table_name + ' WHERE KEY_USER = "'
    + row[1] + '" AND RS = "' + row[0]
    + '" AND DATE_USER > ADDDATE(CONCAT_WS("-", YEAR(NOW()),'
    + ' MONTH(NOW()), "01"), INTERVAL -7 MONTH) AND DATE_USER < "'
    + dt.strftime(dt.now(), '%Y-%m-01') + '  " ORDER BY DATE_USER'
)
value = curs.fetchall()

Код запроса после подстановки значений с проблемной таблицей:
SELECT DATE_USER, NKOD AS cname, `SUM` AS csum 
FROM QWER 
WHERE KEY_USER = "5059024128012" 
AND RS = "56" 
AND DATE_USER > ADDDATE(CONCAT_WS("-", YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), "01"), INTERVAL -7 MONTH) 
AND DATE_USER < "2024-07-01" 
ORDER BY DATE_USER

При подстановке данного запроса в поле SQL в phpMyAdmin ответ возвращается. В python приложение ответ не возвращается, переменная value при попытке получить ее значение в логах не печатается.
При подстановке значений в код запроса других (рабочих) таблиц в переменную value как
и планировалось записывается либо ответ, либо [[]].

Python 3.4 не логинил строки в кириллице.

Текущая версия 3.12.4. Начните с обновления Питона и его модулей.
